# Is localStorage of safari browser accessible by device pwa app in ios?

Tags: angular, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa

I have made an angular application, in which PWA implementation is also done. It runs fine in android device. It basically stores logged in user data in localStorage. So when I open the app through browser and then click on add to home screen. App is installed as PWA app in android and it shows user as logged in in PWA app also. But when I do same thing in IOS, It does not show user as logged in but instead it shows default index page.
In IOS, I open safari browser, click on add to home screen after login into app which stores information of logged in user in localstorage, after installing PWA app, I open app but it directly shows index page means does not show user as logged in.
Is it possible to show user as logged in in the app in IOS PWA app also same as android ?

Comment: hi, Welcome to SO. Please Read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) It would be very good for you in the future.